# How to build a website for PDF upload that the public can download later?

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, web-applications, document-management

I want to build a website/Web app that a company's employees will use to upload documents (PDFs, docx). They (employees) will enter the title of the document as well as tags. Members of the public can then go to a subdomain of the site & search for those documents so that they can view them in the browser or download them.

How do I do this? I'm assuming this is part of what's called document management; hence the title question of this post. Can WordPress or Joomla handle this? Is there a ready-made template that I can use?

I'm also undivided about where to store the uploaded documents. Should they be:

1. Stored in a database (MySQL or MS SQL) or
2. Stored in the file system of the web server or
3. Stored in cloud storage services like Google Drive, On Drive or DropBox?

If I use a database, will it be possible to use the traditional HTML file download method viz a href?

I look forward to your replies. Thanks.

Comment: Anyone? Please help.

Comment: I will advise you should go for **WordPress**. It will ease your file management and uploaded documents can be downloaded again. If you are using WordPress, you do not need to worry about storing the uploaded documents inside the database.

Comment: Thanks. I've used WordPress and yes it makes things much easier. It stores the uploaded file in the WordPress Content folder on the web server.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use WordPress using any theme you like with plugins like:
Forminator, WPForms, WP Extra File Types, and so on.
WordPress will have a fully built and ready-to-use database.
and also you can customize your frontend using plugins like elementor.